# Как вытащить ID сделки из счета, выставленного на основании этой сделки? Битрикс24

Tags: битрикс24

Имеем облако Б24

Менеджер выставляет счет.

Как на вебхуке вытащить ID сделки, на основании которой выставлен счет?

Answer (score 0):

Если знаете ID счета, то можете использовать веб-хук [`crm_invoice_get`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/invoice/crm_invoice_get.php)
В поле [`UF_DEAL_ID`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/invoice/crm_invoice_fields.php) будет храниться ID связанной сделки.